# Reacting to a Button Pressed by the user in a EPD Traits view?

Tags: python, traits, enthought, traitsui

I'm using EPD traits for a basic GUI interface.  I'm able to pop up a settings window using code like this:

```
settings_w.configure_traits(kind="livemodal")
```

The window has 'OK' and 'Cancel' buttons and I want to do something different depending on which button was pressed to exit the window.  Seems like it should be simple but I can't figure out how to set this up.

Theoretically I'd like to do something like this:

```
# Display the settings widget
settings_w.configure_traits(kind="livemodal")

if settings_w.CancelButtonPressed:
    pass
else:
    print "I got the input"
```

But let me know if there's a better or more correct way to do this.

Also FWIW: here's the view properties of my settings window with standard OK and Cancel buttons:

```
view = View( 
    settings_group, 
    title   = 'Settings Editor',
    width = 500,
    buttons = [OKButton, CancelButton, 'Help' ],
    kind = 'modal',
    handler = SaveRestore_Handler()
)
```

Comment: Please provide your entire code so that we can make suggestions that are close to what you would like to do.

Comment: Relevant code is here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5307865

Comment: I basically just want the cancel button to work.  Right now it's functionally identical to the okay button which is just silly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question, checking the output of `configure_traits` should do what you want:

```
result = settings_w.configure_traits(kind="livemodal")

if result:
    print "The user pressed OK."
else:
    print "The user pressed Cancel or closed the window."
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew the answer should be simple like this.  Just didn't know quite how to get there.

Comment: This works great when the user presses cancel or okay, but result returns True in my code when the user closes the window.  How do I make closing the window equivalent to the cancel action?

Comment: @nickv2002 on which platform?

Comment: I'm testing on Windows 7.  Does this behaves differently on other platforms?

Comment: Sorry, I meant: on which backend? The code works correctly for qt (PyQt and PySide), but not for wx. This is probably a bug in TraitsUI. If it's an option, I would recommend switching to qt (set the environment variable `ETS_TOOLKIT=qt4`). Otherwise, you'll need to define your own button...